# Add a HTML Yes/No field to SharePoint Online Yes/No column via JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, submit, yes-no-field

I am building a Custom html form and saving all the fields to a SharePoint Online list. I figured out adding text boxes and choice drop downs via JS/jQuery like,

var xxxxxxxx = $("#xxxxxxxx").val();

var yyyyyyyy = $("#yyyyyy").find("option:selected").text();

but can't figure out how to add HTML Checkbox (Yes/No) to a SharePoint Yes/No column.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Sharepoint yes/no fields are a boolean, meaning it’s true or false. (1/0).

Comment: Tried this, if ($("#HtmlFieldId").is(':checked') === true) { oListItem.set_item('SPColumnInternalName', '1'); }. Didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Tried 1 and Yes, Both don't work. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Try true/false.

Comment: true worked for me. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SharePoint Checkbox (Yes/No) column, it sholuld be $("#checkboxId").is(':checked').

As you can see the picture:

[image]

If you want to set the check box field value, it should be like this:

```
 $("#checkboxId").attr('checked', true)
```

Comment: Hello Michael Han, thanks for your response. I was trying to set the SharePoint column, so i tried this                                                                                               if ($("#HtmlFieldId").is(':checked') === true) { oListItem.set_item('SPColumnInternalName', 'true'); } worked for me